# Should questions which aren't phrased well be closed?

Tags: discussion, questions, closed-questions

The question about GTD influence on PM work ([Has GTD (Getting Things Done) changed your approach to project planning?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/1257/has-gtd-getting-things-done-changed-your-approach-to-project-planning)) has been closed recently.

While I agree it phrased in a way which suggested more a discussion than responses to a question I actually think it was a good subject for a question - it would be enough to rephrase it to be less subjective, e.g. how GTD influence perceiving PM work/PM work itself?

We had kind of similar situation here - the question which used poor English ([Should we vote down questions because of bad English?](https://pm.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111/should-we-vote-down-questions-because-of-bad-english)) and instead of having the question closed author improved it and as a result we have what I believe is a good piece of content.

Now, my concern here is: should we automatically close down questions which aren't phrased well or is it better idea to ask original poster to improve them pointing them what's wrong?

Answer (score 5):

If these questions are worthy of saving, why can't you edit them yourself?

Otherwise, if:

- the post is awful, terrible, beyond saving -- vote to close and delete
- the post is unclear and you have to guess at the author's intentions -- leave a comment
- the post can be improved in some fairly clear ways -- click the edit link and edit it

Comment: I think it is a good idea to copy the answer and paste it into FAQ in "Other people can edit my stuff?!" section. Actually, I personally needed this bit of encouragement to stop being afraid of changing original poster's intention. If they care they'd fix it anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I encourage everyone to clean up the questions using their edit privileges and then **use those reopen votes** if you think the question has been transformed into a good, on-topic, high quality question.

It's important that questions -- even if we like them -- follow the general Stack Exchange guidelines for being [Good, Subjective Questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/).

I have reopened this question since it now meets the guidelines of being a real question, and since there were 2 reopen votes already cast.

I encourage you to continue doing what you're doing and comment and cast close/reopen votes where appropriate.

I also want to encourage community members on the site to join the [Project Management Chat Room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/380/project-management) and start an active discussion surrounding the direction of the site.

I would prefer to see more 500+ rep users participating in helping to make sure questions are cleaned up and on-topic, and this chat room is a great place to get discussions started on where we want to see the site head.